# Animated overlay not transitioning properly on iPad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with a transitioning overlay where the background and the hidden contents do not display until the overlay has completed its transition. The "Example Title" text animates up as it should.

The intended behavior is when the user hovers over the box/image, a green background containing text and an image should transition/slide upwards to cover the box/image. It is working as intended on all the browsers I've tested it on, just not on the iPad using Safari and Chrome.

You can find the example here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQYXGo

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #339752;
}

.btn-cta {
  background-color: #eed507;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #dcb311;
  width: 85%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 13px 15px;
}

.btn-cta:hover,
.btn-cta:focus,
.btn-cta:active {
  color: #333;
}

.col-md-5ths {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.col-md-5ths {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.service {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  text-align: center;
}

.service img.service-icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.service p.service-text {
  padding: 0 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.95vw;
}

.service .btn-cta {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.service::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background 0.30s ease-out;
}

.service_media {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.service_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(12, 48, 41, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.30s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.30s ease-out;
}

.service:hover .service_overlay {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.service_overlay__title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: rgba(12, 48, 41, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-webkit-calc(-100% - 10px));
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 10px));
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.30s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.30s ease-out;
}

.service:hover .service_overlay__title {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section class="all-services">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
        <article class="service" onclick="">
          <img class="service_media" src="http://via.placeholder.com/360x500" alt="" />
          <div class="service_overlay">
            <h2 class="service_overlay__title">Example title</h2>
            <p class="service_overlay__content">
              <img class="service-icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" alt="">
              <p class="service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-cta" href="#">Read More</a></p>
          </div>
        </article>
</section>
```

I've tried using background instead of `background-color` and adding a higher `z-index` to the `.service_overlay`, but this does not seem to change anything.

It seems to work completely fine on other browsers including Safari on Mac. I know these are very trivial attempts at trying to resolve the issue but I really cannot figure out why this is happening on just iPad.

I am also using bootstrap 3.3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Changing `.service_overlay` from `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` resolved the issue on iPad.